# Just loaded ubuntu 14.04. Just getting initramfs

Tags: startup, startup-applications

Have no idea what to do next. Want to get Firefox and go online for my Libre office and yahoo mail. To run on this tower. What commands to use? Where to go for instructions? All i am getting is a prompt (initramfs).  I can type help and get a long list of words. Then back to (initramfs)

Comment: Since you just installed Ubuntu 14.04, it might be easiest to install it again. However if you post your computer make and model there might be known issues requiring special steps.